# Algorithm to rank items lower if they already appear higher in another category

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I'm working on a UI which has a bunch of titles grouped under multiple categories(let's say list of movies). Let's say I have Category 1, Category 2, Category 3 etc., with each category having 20 movies under it. The problem is that some movies are repeated across categories and if they appear in the top 5 in multiple categories, then it looks bad in the UI, since it appears duplicated. The source of this categorization is out of my control and I'm just receiving this data from another service. My requirement is to look for duplicates across categories and if a movie already appeared in a higher ranked(based on order of display) category, penalise it and rank it down in the category. e.g., Movie1 appeared at Rank2 in Category1. Movie1 also appears at Rank4 in Category2. I want to move Movie1 to a much lower rank(say Rank15 or Rank20) in Category2 since it is already appearing at a higher rank in a previous category.

```
Problem:
--------

Category1:
1. Movie1
2. Movie2
3. Movie3
...

Category2:
1. Movie1
2. Movie4
3. Movie5
...

Category3:
1. Movie4
2. Movie6
3. Movie7
...
```

In the case above, I want to rank down Movie1 in Category2 to rank 10 or below since it already appears in Category1 at the same rank or above. Similarly, I want to rank down Movie4 in Category3 to be ranked down since it appears in a higher category at a higher rank.

I was thinking of assigning weights(in descending order) to categories and then calculating the score of each movie based on the rank+weight and then use this to rank down the repeating movies. I'm not an expert in algorithms, ranking etc, but I feel that this would be a common use case and there might already be solutions to such ranking problems. Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: A hash map, movies -> set of ordinals in categories?